# How to shuffle the array in-place

Tags: arrays, algorithm, shuffle

There is an array with equal number of odd and even numbers. The numbers are stored in no particular order. Is it possible to shuffle the array in-place (`O(1)` additional space) so that even numbers are directed to even indexes and odd numbers to odd indexes?

It is of course, trivial to implement using auxiliary storage, the constraint of not using one makes it tough. Plus there is no pattern, in problems like shuffling an array `[a1,a2,a3..an,b1,b2...bn...n1,n2,n3...nn]` to `[a1,b1,c1..n1,a2,b2,c2...n2,...an,bn...nn]`, there is a fixed mapping, which enables one to do it. But there being no such pattern here, is it do-able at all?

Comment: place all odd in odd, equal in equal, and shuffle with fisher yates where your "iterator" and rand() increase by 2 instead of 1?

Comment: Ummm, couldn't make head or tail of what you just said! Fisher-Yates shuffle completely randomizes an array, how can we use that here?

Comment: Its not that hard actually.  Just iterate through the array swapping the even values into even slots and the odd values into odd slots.  All you need is three variables to keep track of the current position in the array, the last even slot used and the last odd slot used.

Comment: @Cupidvogel Fisher yates indeed completely shuffle an array, but you can easily modify it to treat the list as two seperate lists. an alternative could be to first shuffle and then place the odd elements in odd indices and even elements in even indices.

Comment: Can you provide a working pseudo-code? I am having some similar ideas, but they are coming in such a haphazard manner that I am not being able to implement them!

Comment: Hmm, actually, I think that that my approach works, but only if you invert the logic...  I'll have to think about it ...

Comment: Oh, you want the shuffle to be not random? If that is the case, I completely misunderstood you, I thought you want a random shuffle with the special criteria.

Comment: A nice solution has been given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write two iterators. One iterates all array indices of odd numbers at even positions. The other iterates all even numbers at odd positions.

Iterate over both simultaneously, and swap the items pointed to by the iterators until the end of the array. Should have O(n) performance.

Comment: Right. Both iterators will ultimately point to the same number of elements, since number of anomalies have to be same. Thanks. Looks like I have donated my brain to the zoo.

Answer (score 1):

Keep two indices, one for odd numbers, one for evens, and always locate the first even/odd index with odd/even contents, then swap:

```
int even = 0, odd = 1;
do {
    while(even < size && array[even] % 2 == 0) even += 2;
    while(odd < size && array[odd] % 2 == 1) odd += 2;
    if (even < size && odd < size) {
        int temp = array[even];
        array[even] = array[odd];
        array[odd] = temp;
    }
}while(even < size && odd < size);
```

Comment: Yup, got that, the same solution has been suggested by jdv-Jan de Vaan also. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I was typing up the code when the "new answer" appeared, so I didn't notice immediately. Then I saw he had no code, so I left it.

Comment: Sure, no problem. It was helpful all the same..:)